# How split string in c#? (no, not string.split() :)

Tags: c#, .net

I have next string:

```
'Malaysia Index','Mc\'DONALDS CORPORATION','McDonalds','Me,dia'
```

And I need array (or list) of string:

```
Malaysia Index
Mc'DONALDS CORPORATION
McDonalds
Me,dia
```

EDITED:
next code:

```
var s = "'Malaysia Index','Mc\'DONALDS CORPORATION','McDonalds','Me,dia'";
var ss = s.Split(',');
foreach (var res in ss)
    Console.WriteLine(res);
```

do result:

```
'Malaysia Index'
'Mc'DONALDS CORPORATION'
'McDonalds'
'Me                     !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
dia'                    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: Why Split() is bad solution?

Comment: Why not string.split() ?

Comment: Looks like a simple CSV type file, and any CSV parser available on NuGet should be able to do what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split csv whose columns may contain ,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain)

Comment: @YuriDorokhov because the delimited data can contain the delimiter.  That requires a more complex parsing algorithm than a simple `string.Split`.

Comment: @juharr, you are right. Ron's answer is correct.

Comment: OP can't use Split() method because it produce inappropriate result.

Comment: It's not a CSV file; it's clearly using \' as an escape squence for ' inside of '.  CSV has nothing like that.

Comment: @user5090812 there is no standard in csv for a "escape character", using `\'` is perfectly fine, you just need to find a parser that handles it.

Comment: RFC 4180 specifies the standard for csv, including character escaping considerations, and their behavior does not even remotely resemble "C-style" character escaping.  You can write a parser for anything, of course; the difficulty in this case is that we don't have any specification for how it behaves, only guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code produces expected result:

```
s.Trim('\'')
 .Split(new[]{"','"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

it removes 1st and last `'` symbols and splits by `','`

output

```
Malaysia Index
Mc'DONALDS CORPORATION
McDonalds
Me,dia
```

Comment: This works as long as the data cannot have spaces between the quotes and delimiting commas and as long as all delimited data elements are enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @juharr, i agree. that is likely be true for input strings; a worse thing though is possible `\',\'` inside data fields. they would require a more complex parser

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ur text is always in such fomat : 'xxx', 'xxx', ....

do a code to remove the 1st ' and the last '

then replace all ',' to something unique, that would not appear in original text, like 2 pipes ||

now, split the formated text with this new separator ||

and u should get the expected result