# Spliting a string by ; but not if ; is surrounded by " "

Tags: c#, regex

Im trying to split a string by a ;-character.
The only case where i have to ignore this is when ;-character is surrounded by Quotation marks from the both sides, like this ";"
So far i've managed to capture some of the cases with this code

```
Regex.Split(string, "(?=[^\"]);(?=[^\"])", RegexOptions.None)
```

but in a case when my string contains ;" combination (any char but the quotation mark, followed by semicolon, followed by quotation mark) the ;-character is also ignored wich shuold not be the case.

---

Could anyone point me in a right direction to how to ignore ; when it is surrounded by quotation marks from the both sides only?

here is a quick view of what my regex does:
http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3d%5b%5e%5c%22%5d)%3b(%3f%3d%5b%5e%5c%22%5d)&i=%3b+%3b%0d%0a%22%3b%22%0d%0a%22%3b%0d%0a%3b%22

Comment: Use [CSV parser instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain/6543418#6543418).

Comment: Try to find a regex that handles linebreaks inside the doublequotes. Or escaped doublequotes inside the doublequotes or, or, or. Real world csv's are more complex then a simple Regex can handle. I would also vote for a decent proven csv parser.