# Regex replace semicolon between quotation marks C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace all **semicolons** that are enclosed in **quotation marks** with a space. How can I do this in `C#`?

For example:

this string:

`this is an example; "this is other ; example"`

Would return:

`this is an example; "this is other   example"`

I await your help!

Comment: Are there any escaped sequences in your strings? Like ``\\`` for a backslash and `\"` for a double quote? If it is CSV, maybe a CSV parser would be a more appropriate solution than replacing `;` inside double quotes? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain/6543418#6543418).

Comment: Yes it's a .csv file, I'll consider using a parser, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edited: This will work.

```
string yourString = "hello there; \"this should ; be replaced \"";

string fixedString = Regex.Replace(yourString, "(\"[^\",]+);([^\"]+\")", delegate (Match match)
{
    string v = match.ToString();
    return v.Replace(";", " ");
});
```

Comment: Modified to replace with a space.

Comment: This will not work for a string like `"this is an example; \"this is other\" ; \"example\""` as it will remove the second semicolon.

Comment: Hmm, I did not consider that.  I will see.

Answer (score -2):

Try following :

```
string input = "this is an example; \"this is other ; example\"";
            string pattern = "\"(?'prefix'[^;]+);(?'suffix'[^\"]+)\"";

            string output = Regex.Replace(input,pattern,"\"${prefix} ${suffix}\"");
```

Comment: I just tried this and it's also removing the double quotes.

Comment: Now it will not work for a string like `"this is an example; \"this is other\" ; \"example\""` as it will remove the second semicolon