# How to split string on comma, except when comma is parameter separator or part of string

Tags: regex

How to split string on comma, except when comma is parameter separator or part of string?

for example:

> one,"two","three[r,6]",four[6,5],"five,sex"

should be:

> one
>
> "two"
>
> "three[r,6]"
>
> four[6,5]
>
> "five,sex"

I have something like this https://regex101.com/r/n26OSC/1

> ,(?!\d+])

But this still not working when comma is part of string ("five,six" in my example).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try matching with [`"[^"]*"|\w+(?:\[[^][]*])*`](https://regex101.com/r/eQBNFd/1).

Comment: @Wiktor This is very close to what I need, but not working in case like this https://regex101.com/r/eQBNFd/2

Comment: @Wiktor Should split on comma , but should not split on dot.

Comment: You say you are using C#, why bother with regex? Use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain/6543418#6543418).

Comment: @Wiktor This will not work in case when comma is in parameter "param[1,2]". With regex I will have more elegant solution.

Comment: It is much easier to replace the comma inside `[...]` (with `Regex.Replace(s, @"\[[^][]+]", m => m.Value.Replace(",", "TMP_COMMA"))`, use the method I link to, and then restore the commas inside the square brackets than trying to obtain an elegant regex.

Comment: Ok this could be solution. How to replace comma inside ". . ." ?

Comment: Same way as above - just use `"\"[^\"]+\""` regex.

Comment: Thank you. You can post answer so that I can accept.

Comment: Or use an axe...