# Convert regex pattern from php to C#

Tags: c#, php, .net, regex

I have this regex pattern (written for PHP):

`(?:"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|)\K(,)`

I need to use this in dotnet, but `\K` is not supported. Is there an alternative I can use to produce the same effect?

Edit:

This regex is part of this method:

```
private static function fix_json(string $json){
    if(preg_match('/^\[(.+)\]$/s', $json, $matches) > 0){
        $parts = preg_split('/(?:"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|)\K(,)/', $matches[1]); //Splits on commas not inside quotes, ignoring escaped quotes
        foreach($parts as $k => $part){
            $part = trim($part);
            if($part === ""){
                $part = "\"\"";
            }
            $parts[$k] = $part;
        }
        $fixed = "[" . implode(",", $parts) . "]";
        return $fixed;
    }
    return $json;
}
```

This method fixes a JSON list with empty items. E.g. from `[null,,,]` to `[null,"","",""]`. It also should not break with escaped quotation marks inside string values (e.g. `[null,"quote \"",]`) and also with commas inside (e.g. `[null,,"commas,,",]`)

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: Instead of converting, just edit the question to add what you want the regex to do. And some sample input/output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated.

Comment: @Sach updated it.

Comment: What's the expected output for `[null,"quote \"",]` and `[null,,"commas,,",]`?

Comment: Try to use the built-in CSV parser - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain/6543418#6543418

Comment: @Sach `[null,"quote \"",""]` and `[null,"","commas,,",""]` but it only needs to work on the text inside of the square brackets, the first part of the method deals with that.

Comment: Please try the solution in the linked thread and update the question with that try.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i'm using dotnetcore, so that library isn't supported. I think the best solution is regex, there must be a solution surely?

Comment: Not sure, try https://ideone.com/UY33Y3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, that looks great, but it does not seem to fix the last part correctly. In the example you used, the output is `[null,"","\"","",]` rather than `[null,"","\"","",""]`. Is it possible for you to update that?

Comment: @Samueljh1 Try https://ideone.com/3hXiPf