# C# Regex Split Quotes and Comma Syntax Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have the a text file as follows:

```
"0","Column","column2","Column3"
```

I have managed to get the data down to split to the following:

```
"0"
"Column"
"Column2"
"Column3"
```

with `,(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)`, now I want to remove the quotes. I have tested the expression  `[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)` an online regex tester, which gives the correct output im looking for. However, I am getting a syntax error when using the expression:

```
String[] columns = Regex.Split(dataLine, "[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)");
```

> Syntax error ',' expected

I've tried escaping characters but to no avail, am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to find a CSV parser instead.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain/6543418#6543418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are the double quotes inside the regex, the compiler chokes on them, think they are the end of string.
You must escape them, like this:

```
"[^\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|\'([^\']*)"
```

`Edit`:

You can actually do all, that you want with one regex, without first splitting:

```
@"(?<=[""])[^,]*?(?=[""])"
```

Here I use an @ quoted string where double quotes are doubled instead of escaped.

The regex uses look behind to look for a double quote, then matching any character except comma ',' zero ore more times, then looks ahead for a double quote.

**How to use**:

```
string test = @"""0"",""Column"",""column2"",""Column3""";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=[""])[^,]*?(?=[""])");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(test))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

C# might be escaping the backslash. Try:

```
String[] columns = Regex.Split(dataLine, @"[^\s""']+|"([^""]*)""|\'([^\']*)");
```

Comment: This is still a syntax error for the same reason. You need to use `""` to represent a single `"` inside of a verbatim string literal (using the `@` syntax).

Comment: Thanks - good pickup; fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes inside of your regular expression, as they're closing the string literal. Also, to handle 'unrecognized escape sequences', you'll need to escape the `\` in `\s`.

Two ways to do this:

- Escape all the characters of concern using backslashes: `"[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|\'([^\']*)"`
- Use the `@` syntax to denote a "verbatim" string literal. Double quotes still need to be escaped, but instead using `""` for every `"`: `@"[^\s""']+|""([^""]*)""|'([^']*)"`

Regardless, when I test out your new regular expression it appears to be capturing some empty groups as well, see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1WQE4R