# C# Regex to split row with delimiter, but ignore delimiter inside quotes

Tags: c#, regex, split, delimiter, quotes

I am getting lots of files, in which I have zero control, that I need to split based on delimiter.
But I don't want to split when the delimiter is inside quotes.
So, column1, column2, column3 is

```
column1
column2
column3
```

however
column1, "column2," column3 is

```
column1
"column2," column3
```

This works using this RegEx (under C#)

```
((?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\"(,|$)+)|(?<=,|^)[^,\"]*(?=,|$))
```

Now, my problem is when there is a line with only one double quote (opening, or closing only)
For example column1, column2", column3
returns

```
column1

column3
```

while it should return

```
column1
column2"
column3
```

I have found lots of RegEx related, but all of them fail in the above particular example.

Comment: It seems you are parsing a CSV file, why not use the [built-in library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20523165/3832970) ([another link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508572/3832970))? and if you just need to [parse a CSV string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543418/3832970), not a file.

Comment: The code is using LINQ to get the collection of rows, that iare split using the RegEx. I cannot change that part as it is used by many other components.

Comment: So your delimiter should be any line in the file that is not enclosed in quotes?

Comment: What is the code? If you use `.Matches`, you can probably just use `Regex.Matches(text, "(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^,])+")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew almost works, but it skips columns that are null.

Comment: @wizard Then I think `Regex.Matches(text, "(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^,])+|(?<![^,])(?![^,])")` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match all the fields you need using

```cs
Regex.Matches(text, "(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^,])+|(?<![^,])(?![^,])")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5C%22%5B%5E%5C%22%5D*%5C%22%7C%5B%5E%2C%5D%29%2B%7C%28%3F%3C!%5B%5E%2C%5D%29%28%3F!%5B%5E%2C%5D%29&i=column1%2C%20column2%2C%20column3%0D%0Acolumn1%2C%20%22column2%2C%22%20column3%0D%0Acolumn1%2C%20column2%22%2C%20column3%2C%2C%2C). *Details*:

- `(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^,])+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` (if there can be `""` inside, replace with `"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"`)
  - `|` - or
  - `[^,]` - any char but `,`
- `|` - or
- `(?<![^,])(?![^,])` - a location that is either at the start of string or is immediately preceded with a comma, and is either at the end, or immediately followed with a comma.