# Split a string if delimiter is between single quotes

Tags: c#, string, split

**General Info**
Working on a game mod where users are able to insert custom data into a configuration file using a basic string.

**The problem**
I'm trying to split the string in such a way that data is clearly separable without limiting user input, with the exception of quotes. The issue is that the approaches I've tried did not deliver the expected result.

**Exampe input / output**
String input:

```cs
String str = "'Item Name:Item ID','Item name with, comma:Some ID','Some Name:Some ID'";
```

Expected output:

```
'Item Name:Item ID'
'Item name with, comma:Some ID'
'Some Name:Some ID'
```

The single quotes in the output are not important to me, but the colon is (as to separate names with IDs)

**What I've tried myself**

```cs
String str = "'Item Name:Item ID','Item name with, comma:Some ID','Some Name:Some ID'";
        
String[] separator = { "','" };
Int32 count = 100;

String[] strlist = str.Split(separator, count, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach(String s in strlist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Result output:

```
'Item Name:Item ID
Item name with, comma:Some ID
Some Name:Some ID'
```

I've also tried `String[] separator = { "," };` instead, with the result:

```
'Item Name:Item ID'
'Item name with
 comma:Some ID'
'Some Name:Some ID'
```

How should I adept my code to get the desired result?

Comment: You have actually a CVS format (with `'` as a *quotation mark* and `,` as a *separator*), just try any *CsvParsers*

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain-comma)

Comment: @FortyTwo Thanks a lot for that example and thanks Dmitry for the advise. I think this question can be closed as a duplicate of that question FortyTwo :)

Comment: You can use [`Regex.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-7.0) with `"(?<='),(?=')"` as pattern (positives lookahead and lookbehind won't be part of the split)