# How to read .csv file extension in .net C#

Tags: c#, file, csv

How to read .csv file extension in .net C#

Comment: Do you wish to read the file contents, or simply the file extension???

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906841/csv-parser-reader-for-c & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375410/very-simple-c-csv-reader - please search before asking a question.  And this question definitely doesn't deserve an upvote!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading CSV files in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-csv-files-in-net)

Answer (score 3):

I just write my own - it's a one-liner!

```
using System.IO.File;

return ReadAllLines(@"C:\V3.txt").Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToList();
```

This will return a list where each item is a string[], contain each of the comma separated values.

Comment: That ones going to cause problems if the data contains embedded commas or double quotes.

Comment: Very true. If I have to suffer with delimited files I always insist on non-comma delimited; tab or pipe delimited is much better.

Comment: @ShrutiKapoor what do you mean? What's changed - which part doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

FileHelper has mostly done the trick for me and it iss easy to use and has reasonable examples at the home page: http://www.filehelpers.com/