# Inserting data line by line from datagridview

Tags: c#

I am stuck at one point.

I am able to read data from csv file and display it on data gird view. Now, I want to insert those data (which is display in datagridview)  into database.Also, at time of insert data with same primary key should get update.

I tried different way like stored procedure, loop but its not working.

I couldn't able to understand how should I read data line by line from datagridview and insert into database.

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/209616

Answer (score 1):

Step #1, [parse CSV into DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805656/how-do-i-parse-a-text-file-using-c/4806540#4806540).

Step #2, set DataGridView.DataSource to the DataTable or a BindingSource attached to the DataTable.

Step #3, use a [TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx) to write DataTable into database.