# C# Convert .lst file to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list

I have a .lst file. Which looks like this. But I thougt there is a better, a faster and easier way to import the .lst file. Because excel can import it, so maybe its possible in c#, too.

**How do I get a .lst file to an Array in c# ? Which looks like the excel table**

*DXF-Dateiname Funktionsnummer       Blattnummer   Benennung

DXFO0001.dxf  114D197 DECK          01            DECKBLATT
 DXFO0002.dxf  114D197 G72           01
 DXFO0003.dxf  114I197 BL            01
 DXFO0004.dxf  114I197 BL            02*

Normally the file is way bigger i just posted this little part for testing.

I can import the file to excel.

[image: excel image with date from above]

So I thougt I can import the .lst file with c# to an array. I know how to get file in c# like this function from microsoft.

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

public class RecursiveFileProcessor 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        foreach(string path in args) 
        {
            if(File.Exists(path)) 
            {
                // This path is a file
                ProcessFile(path); 
            }               
            else if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
            {
            // This path is a directory
            ProcessDirectory(path);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path);
        }        
    }        
}


// Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories 
// that are found, and process the files they contain.
public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory) 
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory.
    string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
    foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
        ProcessFile(fileName);

    // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
    string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
    foreach(string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
        ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
}

// Insert logic for processing found files here.
public static void ProcessFile(string path) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path);       
}
```

}

Comment: The C# cod eyou pasted is about listing directories, not about parsing and .lst file (which looks like a CSV file to me) What is your question exactly?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd How do I get a .lst file to an Array in c# ? Whicht looks like the excel table.

Comment: Can you open the file with notepad a share a part of it?

Comment: @aloisdg The data of the file is _italic_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public string[][] ProcessFile(string fileName)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllText(fileName).Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // skip first line
    return lines.Skip(1).Select(line => line.Split(new[] {" "}, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This is good but just a one dimenstional Array I need a two dimensional Array string[][] (like the excel sheet )

Comment: that i just brilliant and working in my code. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a CSV to Array code? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375410/very-simple-c-sharp-csv-reader) is something that might be what you need.

Comment: I want like a two dimensional Array